# Case / Package Products in Magento 2

Tags: product, magento-2.0, custom

I have this requirement:

A product should have each individual price and case / package price.

For each product, N items make a case. For example: In product, A 20 items makes a case. In product B 5 items make a case.

When a user enters the quantity, the code should automatically check how many case can be purchased and how many individual product can be purchased.

For example: If a user types 125 quantity, it should automatically check the case product count (20 items in this case),

125 products can be purchased as 6 cases (20 items in a case) and 5 individual items.

I hope my comment is understandable.

Please refer to the image attached.

[image]

Comment: Do you know any extension to do that?

Comment: Is their any scenario in which you have discount on case ?or just want to show customer like that on checkout ?

Like in above you are just displaying and product price is same in both cases.